# Where did this Emanuel Lasker quote come from?

Tags: history

In the book by the late master Irving Chernev "The Chess Companion" he gives a list of chess quotes. My favourite one was:

"The student can learn more in ten hours of properly tutored instruction than in 10 years of trial and error" : Dr Emanuel Lasker.

I might not have this quote absolutely right. If not this is very close; it might be the student 'would'...rather than the student 'can'. Anyway, I have never managed to trace this quote. Was it in Lasker's books, chess lectures such as the London lectures, or in his chess annotations? Or did he just say it? If so was it at a chess tournament or somewhere notable?

I'd like to know. Not out of skepticism. I have faith in Chernev. Rather, because it's my favourite quote! I also wonder if it was in German - Dr Lasker was German. If it is a translation then please keep in mind that I only understand English.

Comment: All my Googling for an answer hasn't found one. Maybe I need to find a specialist Emanuel Lasker scholar?

Comment: The correct wording is "properly taught, a student can learn more in a few hours than he would find out in ten years of untutored trial and error". The oldest reference to the quote I found is in this [newspaper article](http://www.newspapers.com/newspage/10292301/) of 1973.

Comment: @lodebari that's a great answer! Would you mind posting it?

Comment: Yes! Lodebari, that is a fantastic answer!

Answer (score 6):

The correct wording is "properly taught, a student can learn more in a few hours than he would find out in ten years of untutored trial and error". The oldest reference to the quote I found is in this [newspaper article](http://www.newspapers.com/newspage/10292301/) of 1973.

Answer (score 2):

The January 1953 [Chess Review](https://archive.org/details/ChessReview1953/page/n1) on the back of the front cover, right below *Chernev's Chess Corner*, has a "Thought for the month":

> Properly taught, a student can learn more in a few hours, than he would find out in ten years of untutored trial and error. -Ed. Lasker

This implies that it was [Edward Lasker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Lasker), not Emanuel Lasker, who said it. I didn't find its exact source yet, though.

Comment: Thats interesting. Because that shows that Chernev or whoever wrote the 1953 piece changed his mind and at various points gave the quote to Edward or Emanuel Lasker.